# Is there a way to assure that one method executes after another when using DispatcherObjectInvoker.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to assure the second statement executes after the first one?

```
DispatcherObjectInvoker.Invoke(_layouts,
    () =>
        _layouts.RaiseEvent(new LayoutEventArgs(
            MainScreen.ChangedLayoutEvent,
            this)));

DispatcherObjectInvoker.Invoke(_layouts, Grid.Refresh);
```

I'm accessing an Grid that is touched in the first statement. The refresh of the grid is working in about 80% of the cases only. I obviously have a race condition here.

Comment: what is `DispatcherObjectInvoker` ? Is it just `Dispatcher` ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not make them both part of the same action?

```
DispatcherObjectInvoker.Invoke(_layouts, () => 
{
     _layouts.RaiseEvent(new LayoutEventArgs(MainScreen.ChangedLayoutEvent,
                                             this));
     Grid.Refresh();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a `DispatcherObjectInvoker` is, but I will assume it's a wrapper for `Dispatcher` or something.

If it is, if you call `Invoke()`, it is a blocking call. So your second call is guaranteed to be after your first call.

However, if your intent is to have those be asynchronous calls, you should use `BeginInvoke`. The `DispatcherPriority` parameter helps ensure that calls made to the same priority level are in the same order. So, if `_layouts` refers to the `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` priority (or any other priority), the calls are guaranteed to be in the same order.

Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx).